# Connection to a basic WebAPI fails

Tags: c#, swagger

I am trying to test the possibility to convert all my WCF service to WebAPI but so far it's a mess. WCF is easy because you create a default project and add 1 or 2 sample method that return anything then add as a service by using the http address and it works out of the box.

On WebAPI you add connected service and type the address and it throw errors so obviously out of the box it has errors and is missing stuff to actually work.

**My question is what is missing to WebAPI made with .NET6 to be able to be connected to ?**

Following Microsoft example what i should do is to run the service obviously. Then use the path of the json file generated by swagger and input that in the URL of the connected services, give it a namespace and a classname and your good to go.

**Step 1 : Running the service**

This works i can call the basic 3 method i made for test purpose that return `string`, `List<string>` and `List<List<string>>` and i can execute the "tryout" button and they output everything that it needs

**Step 2 : Copy the json file path provided by Swagger**

I assumed that this url is good by default. I can click it and i see the definition which seems good.
[image]

**Step 3 : Create and empty console app and add the connected service**

When adding the connected service i pick OpenAPI as it's the only option anyway.
Then it asks for File or URL that i put my value form the service that is running. In this case this is : `https://localhost:44341/swagger/v1/swagger.json`. I then choose the namespace of `WebTest1` and classname of `WebTest2` as i dont care and click next

**Step 4 : Configuration progress**

This is where i have the error which is where i see that the service that can actually run cannot be connected to

> Checking project for required NuGet packges... Downloading service
> reference from https://localhost:44341/... ErrorFailed adding service
> reference(s). Failed to download metadata file from :
> https://localhost:44341/.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here. 1) You have both your API app and Console app running at the same time? 2) Are you simply making an HTTP request from your Console app to your API or trying to connect to it another way? Can you add your Console App code? 3) If the WebAPI is running `https://localhost:44341/` should be the correct base url and you should be able to hit the `/api/Data` end points. Have you tried using something like Postman to reach your endpoints?

Comment: Is your localhost actually `https://` and if yes, do you use a self-signed certificate? It might be that the "Failed to download" error happens because of a self-signed cert.

Comment: I am running the webapi with visual studio using F5. It runs. I can browse it and test all the methods in the swagger page displayed in my browser as i already mentioned in the question. I use another console app and i am just trying to add the connected server while the webapi is still running in the other visual studio

Comment: "...i am just trying to add the connected server while the webapi is still running in the other visual studio" can you show us the code you are using to try and do this?

Comment: @ProdigalTechie I am not using any code. It's the visual studio window to add connected service. [this window throws, it shows the error on clicking next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxWxi.png)

Comment: Gotcha! I'm only getting the error message you got if my WebAPI project is not running in Visual Studios. I start debugging my WebAPI in one Visual Studio window then open the other App in another Visual Studio window when I go to connect the OpenAPI service it configures without error.

Comment: @ProdigalTechie Ok so you get the error when running the WebAPI hosted in IIS (this is what i understand from what you are saying) but you get no error from running the WebAPI from the Visual Studio project. That mean we have the inverted result.

Comment: What does your Program.cs (or Startup.cs) look like for `app.UseSwagger();` and `app.UseSwaggerUI();` in your WebAPI app? Is it only if you are in a particular environment?

Comment: @ProdigalTechie yes it's exactly like that. All i did is create a .net 6 asp.net core web api. Gave it a name, Deleted the weather controller and the weather class in the main root and just create a dummy controller with 3 methods and ran it and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the temporary fix. I was also able to copy this project over to a colleague and the issue is the same. The problem lies into Visual Studio defaulting for some reason on the debug option of IIS Express which does properly run the service when you press F5 and your browser open normally and you can test things out. The problem is that when you project runs under IIS (actually configured like it would be the real deal) or IIS Express (the only IIS option in the debug setting) you **cannot** from another application connect to that service.

However if you switch the debug option to the project name and run your WebApi with that instead it also works as expected from the browser that it open but you now can actually add that service from another application without any error.

Personally i have a third option which is WSL which i "guess" is the linux sub system i can't tell as this crash when i try to start and there is no help for the UI of Visual Studio to help understand these menu options.

Now i still have a problem to attach to one running in a real IIS which is probably linked to the same reason why IIS Express debug doesn't work. So i now know that the base code works and now it's an issue of finding why the default doesn't let other application consume from IIS / IIS Express.

For reference purpose this is the debug menu in question where the IIS Express option is not working but selecting the project name like pointed out on the picture actually works.

[image]